# Reference query results with outerjoin in Flask/SQLAlchemy/jinja

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask, jinja2

I have the following query:

```
last_entry = Table.query \
                  .group_by(Table.email) \
                  .order_by(Table.date) \
                  .subquery()

results = db.session.query(User, last_entry.c.id)  \
    .outerjoin(last_entry, User.email == last_entry.c.email)
```

This gets the the needed data, however I am unable to access this "last_entry" row data. How to get that to show in the template?

I am rendering it with this line:

```
return render_template('users.html', users=results.all())
```

I have tried some solutions with `user['last_entry']` and similar things, but without success. I can access the data from the User table, by just using fields from User table, like `user['first_name']`, but can't do the same for the joined table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `session.query()` you should specify a list of entities that you want to see in the results:

```
results = db.session.query(User, last_entry).outerjoin(last_entry, User.email == last_entry.c.email)
```

Or, you can make use of [add_entity()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.add_entity):

```
results = session.query(User).outerjoin(last_entry, User.email == last_entry.c.email).add_entity(last_entry)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmmm, the first suggestion looks similar to my line as well? But I still can't access that `last_entry` value. It should be available as `user['last_entry']`?

Comment: Should be. Btw, can you try to pass `results` to the template as is, like `return render_template('users.html', users=results)`?

Comment: This lead me to a right answer.

The solution, when I went through "user in users", was to reference the user.Class.property, and that additional field I added was available user.id, and that solved the issue. Thanks for the help!